# How to open and read contents from an unsaved file

Tags: visual-c++, file-io

I want to open and read a file which has not been saved. I would like to do this in Windows OS with VC++ or by means of a batch file only.

If I open up the file by normal method of fopen or fopen_s, the file is opened in the last saved manner which is not what I want. I want all the data which is present in the file but not yet saved.

I have read something on this in this link. [Similar question](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/46147-how-do-you-read-data-in-an-unsaved-notepad-file/). But I am unable to follow the scripts. Can someone please convert it into a batch and give it to me?

Comment: If the file hasn't been saved, I don't see how it could be opened and read because that would imply that the file was being read *before* it was written. If you want to read a file into one program while it is being written by another program, perhaps your need would be met better by using a [pipe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877697/communicating-between-two-child-processes-with-pipes) between the two processes?

Comment: I can't use pipe because I have don't have control over the process which is writing the data into the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you mean read the contents from a window or control.
Files are made only after data is saved.

To read contents of a window like the edit control in Notepad, you first have to get a handle to the control. You can do this using `FindWindow` to first get the handle of the main window and then use it in `FindWindowEx` to get the handle of the edit control.

Once you have the handle of the control, you can send it `WM_GETTEXT` message using `SendMessage` to read the text it contains.

Please note that this may not work for all applications. For example, MS-Word uses a rich edit control which had its own methods to fetch text.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the problem is FindWindow works only for those applications which have a window. My software writes into the notepad in the background and doesn't appear in the foreground in form of any window. Please can you tell me how should I go about it?

Comment: If you mean that the notepad window is not visible or is hidden, you can still use `FindWindow`.